# Diferencia mas o menos 1 decimal

Tags: php, variables, comparaciones

Necesito comparar dos variables que son valores moneda, donde si son iguales o tienen una diferencia de más o menos 0.01, arroje el resultado.
No sé cómo hacer la comparación de más o menos 0.01.

Mi código:

```
if($PrecioTotalServicioRemitoGuardado!=$TotalRemitoServicio2d){
echo 'Precio guardado: '.$PrecioTotalServicioRemitoGuardado.''; 
echo 'Precio nuevo: '.$TotalRemitoServicio2d.'';    
echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restar las dos variables, calcular el [valor absoluto (abs)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.abs.php) de esa resta, y comparar el resultado con 0.01

```
abs(var1 - var2) < 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba a poner más condicionales dentro de ese, con este formato para ver las diferencias:

```
if (a - b <= 0.01) && (a - b >= -0.01)
    ~condición~
```

Espero ser de ayuda.